# Greatest count for each customer in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
customer | category | count 
------------+---------------+-------
    4846 | Vegetables | 1
    1687 | Fast-Food  | 7
    2654 | Drink      | 2
    2654 | Vegetables | 3
    1597 | Vegetables | 1
    4846 | Drink      | 2
    2654 | Fast-Food  | 1
    1597 | Drink      | 6
    1597 | Snack      | 3
```

how can i select the category which has greatest count for each customer for this table?

Answer (score 1):

This is called the mode.  You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (customer) t.*
from t
order by customer, count desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `row_number()`.

```
select
    customer,
    category,
    count
from
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by customer order by count desc) as rnk
    from yourTable
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code for you try:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM (SELECT customer, max(count) as max_count
      FROM customers 
      GROUP BY customer) as max_count_table
JOIN customers as c on max_count_table.customer = c.customer and max_count_table.max_count = c.count
```

Result:
[image]